# Stuck on If Else Conditions "java"

Tags: java, android

Am a trying to compare two strings one from my api another form firebase the problem is where when they match it does not execute the condition am expecting but executes the conditions which seems that they did not match here is my code snippet using retrofit for my api

```
for (final StudentClearanceSNAL studentClearance: studentClearancess.getStudentClearanceSNAL()) {

    //firebase checking for registrationnumber
    String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            StudentDataFirebase studentDataFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentDataFirebase.class);
            String registationnumber = studentDataFirebase.getRegistrationNumber();
            if (registationnumber.equals(studentClearance.getRegistrationno()) && (studentClearance.getAmount() == 0 && studentClearance.getReason().equals("none"))) {
                //execute a simple toast
            } else if (registationnumber.equals(studentClearance.getRegistrationno()) && (studentClearance.getAmount() != 0 && !studentClearance.getReason().equals("none"))) {
                //executes a simple toast
            } else if (!studentClearance.getRegistrationno().equals(registationnumber)) {
                Executes a simple toast
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Thats my data set on my api**

`````
"students": [
    {
        "_id": "5e74775518b0f00c0123925b",
        "registrationno": "IWR/D/2016/0024",
        "firstname": "Mariam",
        "lastname": "Wamigomba",
        "amount": 10000,
        "reason": "lost key ",
        "__v": 0
    }]}````



**Here is the logcat results comparing the data**

    ````2020-07-03 16:42:04.823 17516-17516/I/ContentValues: Registration Number:
        [INF/D/2017/0004](15)
        [IWR/D/2016/0024](15)
    2020-07-03 16:42:04.838 17516-17516/com./ContentValues: Registration Number:
        [INF/D/2017/0004](15)
        [INF/D/2017/0004](15)
    2020-07-03 16:42:04.851 17516-17516/I/ContentValues: Registration Number:
        [INF/D/2017/0004](15)
        [FOR/E/2016/0024](15)````

**Now if the registration number matches it still executes the last option which is not correct what am i missing fellas from there**
`````

Comment: Can you show us the values of each of the things you test in your `if` tests?

Comment: Is there perhaps whitespace in one of the values?

Comment: the string are like this inf/d/2012/0907 format

Comment: strings that are in this form AZX/F/2090/900 @markspace

Comment: This think you can solve it easily with careful debugging!! Check the output of variables while debugging what else? :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of duplication in your logic. Try:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Registration Number:\n[" + registationnumber + "](" + registationnumber.length() + ")\n[" + studentClearance.getRegistrationno() + "](" + studentClearance.getRegistrationno().length() + ")");

if (registationnumber.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(studentClearance.getRegistrationno().trim()) {
    if(studentClearance.getAmount() == 0 && studentClearance.getReason().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
          // case 1
    } else if (studentClearance.getAmount() != 0 && !studentClearance.getReason().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
            // case 2
    } else {
            // you had not considered this case
            // case 3
    }
} else {
      // case 4
}
```

Comment: that one keeps going to the last statement even if the registration number is not available on the api

Comment: brother one more thing the registration number is always available on the firebase but its availability on the api may be or not present hopes thats add some more info to solve this problem

Comment: I have amended my answer to address a potential problem with case sensitivity. Perhaps you could check for Strings being null first, before my logic above, but you haven't said an error is being thrown, so that will unlikely solve your problem. You need to explain your problem more clearly; perhaps provide a specific example data set.

Comment: i have added the data that is available in the api just a sample

Comment: I have added a line to my answer above that will dump the key details to Logcat so that you can be assured that the registration numbers match precisely. Can I suggest you post the precise output as seen in Logcat?

Comment: yes brother it shows several results by showing the two registration number in comparison and yes there 's much but still the logic jumps to the last statement have posted the logcat results

Comment: In the log you have posted, only the 2nd example shows matching Strings. Is this what you expected? Are you still saying that in that 2nd case `a.equals(b)` is returning `false`?

Comment: the strings matches but instead of going to the first option it goes to the last else block which is not true

Comment: the problem is why does it jumps all the conditions that is true and goes to the last as if it is not matching

Comment: Please confirm you are using my proposed logic in my answer, rather than yours. I have now annotated the cases. Please use these annotations to tell me where your code lands.

Comment: Case 4 using my logic or the final else block of your original logic? please use my proposed logic because this will make it much clearer where the error lies.

Comment: am using your logic sir but it still falls on the last else block

Comment: am using your logic but it falls on the Case 4 inspite that the strings are matched